# Creating a div that occupies 100% of height and 75% of width of body

Tags: html, css

I'm kind of new to HTML/CSS and I don't know how to make what I wrote in the title.
I mean, it was working before and now I must have messed up somewhere and it stopped working.

My code is kind of bigger than this, but the rest is commented to it isn't used.

```css
body {
        background-color: red;
        margin: 0em;

    }
    
    #main {
        background-color: #E3E3E3;
        width: 75%;
        margin: auto;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
    <html>
     <head>
     </head>
     <body>
         <div id="main">
         </div>
     </body>
    <html>
```

Shouldn't that code create what I want? When I set height to em/px it works, but not on percentages, although they work on the width.

I have the background color red to easily tell them apart by the way.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using a doctype declaration?  It could be due to quirks mode.

Comment: yup. <!DOCTYPE HTML>

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the body width and height to 100%.

```
body {
background-color: red;
margin: 0em;
width:100%;
height:100%;


}

#main {
background-color: #E3E3E3;
width: 75%;
margin: auto;
height: 100%;
}
```

Since you have no text or trees in the document body, the height is going to collapse.

Comment: A `width` of `100%` is not required.

Comment: You also need `html { height: 100%; }`. You will probably want to use `min-height: 100%` instead for `#main` so that it can expand with content. [like this example](http://jsbin.com/vuyuco/1/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
#main {
    background-color: #E3E3E3;
    width: 75%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; /* Top as suggested by t.niese */
    left: 18%; /* Adjust the value as needed to get it to be centered */
}
```

[See working example](http://jsfiddle.net/zvn7gtvc/)

**Note:** Setting the body dimension is important as noted by magnetwd

Comment: Thank you. It works like that, although you don't really need margin and bottom on your code. I think. And the correct percentage on the left for it to be in the middle is 12.5% for anyone who is wondering ((100-75)/2)=12.5

EDIT: Just realized you also need bottom and I have no idea why.

Comment: If there is a special reason why you use  `bottom: 0` instead of `top: 0`, then you should explain it. Anyway I would suggest not to use a position that is different to `static` and especially `absolute` if it is not required.

Comment: the Bottom property value of 0 makes sure that it stretches from top to bottom as long as the height property value is 100%.

Comment: You will have the same effect with `top: 0` when the height is `100%`. `bottom: 0` is not essentially wrong, but it has the meaning attach the `#main` element to the `bottom` of its offset parent with a distance of `0` and set the height to `100%`. But as the origin of in html is at `left`/`top` `0` I would suggest to use `top: 0` in this case.